# Groupby, apply function and combine results in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to group the ids by Type column and apply a function on the grouped stocks that returns the first row where the Value column of the grouped stock is not NaN and copies it into a separate data frame.

I got the following so far:

```
dummy data: 

df1 = {'Date': ['04.12.1998','05.12.1998','06.12.1998','04.12.1998','05.12.1998','06.12.1998'],
        'Type': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
           'Value': ['NaN', 100, 120, 'NaN', 'NaN', 20]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns = ['Date', 'Type', 'Value'])

print (df2)
         Date  Type Value
0  04.12.1998     1   NaN
1  05.12.1998     1   100
2  06.12.1998     1   120
3  04.12.1998     2   NaN
4  05.12.1998     2   NaN
5  06.12.1998     2    20

import pandas as pd

selectedStockDates = {'Date': [], 'Type': [], 'Values': []}
selectedStockDates = pd.DataFrame(selectedStockDates, columns = ['Date', 'Type', 'Values'])

first_valid_index = df2[['Values']].first_valid_index()

selectedStockDates.loc[df2.index[first_valid_index]] = df2.iloc[first_valid_index]
```

The code above should work for the first id, but I am struggling to apply this to all ids in the data frame. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's `mask` the values in dataframe where the values in column `Value` is `NaN`, then `groupby` the dataframe on `Type` and aggregate using `first`:

```
df2['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df2['Value'], errors='coerce')
df2.mask(df2['Value'].isna()).groupby('Type', as_index=False).first()
```

---

```
   Type        Date  Value
0   1.0  05.12.1998  100.0
1   2.0  06.12.1998   20.0
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps for finding the first date of each stock. My initial idea was to keep the indices in the new data frame to simply add +7 to the index to find the 7th value of one stock for example. I have clarified my example above.

Comment: @Rbeginner In that case i think you can do something like `df2.reset_index().mask(df2['Value'].isna()).groupby('Type', as_index=False).first().set_index('index')`

Comment: How would I get the 7th trading day of the stock using your commented code? So where in that line of code can I add +7, so that the index adds up to the 7th day? Thanks in advance

Comment: Lets discuss [`here`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219265/ds5)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `groupby` and `first` but you need to make sure that your null values are `np.nan` and not strings like they are in your sample data:

```
df2.groupby('Type')['Value'].first()
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps for finding the first date of each stock. But my initial idea was to keep the indices in the new data frame to simply add +7 later on to find the 7th value of one stock for example